# Integration between 3 products

Tags: integration

Is it possible to get a solution to the following

$$\int_0^t xe^xf''(x)$$

I am unsure as how to use the chain rule and furthermore, how I would insert a limit into $f''(x)$ for example, is it simply $f''(t)$?

Comment: What is the exact question you're trying to answer? There's certainly ways to manipulate that integral, for example to express it as $g(t) + \int_0^t h(x)f(x) \ dx$. But to what end?

Comment: Can i just not do the chain rule on it?

Comment: Sure, but can i do this over 3 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate by parts (what you call chain rule, I assume) $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$ where

$$ u=xe^x , dv=f''(x)dx, du=e^x+xe^x, v=f'(x)$$

and we have (assuming $f''=\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$)

$$ \int_0^t xe^x f''(x)dx = xe^x f'(x)\bigr|_0^t + \int_0^t (e^x+xe^x) f'(x) dx $$

You can do the integration by parts a second time with

$$ u=e^x+xe^x, dv=f'(x)dx, du=(2e^x+xe^x)dx, v=f(x)$$

and we get

$$ xe^x f'(x)\bigr|_0^t + \int_0^t (e^x+xe^x) f'(x) dx = xe^x f'(x)\bigr|_0^t + (e^x+xe^x)f(x)\bigr|_0^t + \int_0^t (2+x)e^x f(x)dx$$

We can take limits the usual way:

$$xe^x f'(x)\bigr|_0^t + (e^x+xe^x)f(x)\bigr|_0^t + \int_0^t (2+x)e^x f(x)dx =\\ te^t f'(t)-0f(0) + (e^t+te^t)f(t)-(1+0)f(0) + \int_0^t (2+x)e^x f(x)dx =\\ te^t f'(t) + (e^t+te^t)f(t)-f(0) + \int_0^t (2+x)e^x f(x)dx $$

You do need to know the funtion $f(x)$ in order to find the integral $\int_0^t (2+x)e^x f(x)dx$, though.